# How to replace character in second word of a String?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like below

```
String inp = "Monday 02nd January 2017";
```

I want to replace last two characters from second word. My output should be like below.

```
Monday 02 January 2017
```

I have created one regex which gives me the last two character of second word in a string, but am not sure how to replace them with nothing.

Here is my regex and replace function

```
regex = "^(?:\\S+\\s){1}\\S+(\\w{2})\\b.*";
String op = inp.replaceAll(inp.replaceAll(regex, "$1"), "");
```

Because sometimes happens like, My input string is like `August 01st January 2017` and when I replace "st" it replaces all "st" in a string. I dont want to happen like that. It should replace exact last two character from second word.

May I know please how can I achieve this in java ?

Comment: What about `String op = inp.replaceAll("(\\d)(?:st|nd|rd|th)\\b", "$1");`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Its works like a magic...!! Can you please explain your regex ...?

Comment: Impossible, the result is [`Monday 02 January 2017`](https://ideone.com/U0Kxe2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Yes that was my bad, I was using replace instead of replaceall

Comment: My idea is already taken by wp78de, let them explain in the answer below.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Can you please share in your regex how you are targeting only second word of string ? And what is the importance of \\d in regex ? Can you please put some light ?

Comment: My idea is not to target the second word, only to remove all ordinal numeral suffixes glued to a diigt (`\d`). If you want to target a second word and remove these suffixes, you may use `String op = inp.replaceFirst("^(\\W*\\w+\\W+\\w+)(?:st|nd|rd|th)\\b", "$1")`. See [**this Java demo**](https://ideone.com/i8el7k).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?<=\w )(\w+)\w{2}
```

Use this with `replaceFirst` and pass in the replacement as `$1`.

Explanation:

The lookbehind finds the start of the second word, since you are using `replaceFirst`, it will find the first match (the second word) and stop, instead of carrying on to find the third and fourth words.

Then we capture a bunch of word characters followed by 2 word characters not captured.